# Android shared element transtion from one activity to another

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

So i have recycler view that holds images that are downloaded from the internet. I have a onClick listener for that images that executes a new activity.

I would like to transit the image that was clicked to antoher activity.
I tried it already *ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation* method, but it doesn't show. It look like the image in the second activity does not get populated.

It would be appricited if somebody knows a solution to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do then in the 1st activity that downloads the image I would save the image to a file, and pass the filename as a string to the second activity as an extra:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imageFile", "/path/of/the/saved/image");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the second activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String imageFile = bundle.getString("imageFile");
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do. I though that the makeSceneTransitionAnimation method gets the image source and puts into the new activity